# convert string into numeric data in the dataframe using python

Tags: python, azure, python-3.x, machine-learning, dataframe

If we have field like in the dataframe

```
A12
A13
A13
A12
A14
```

We need to convert this string into

```
A12   1
A13   2
A13   2
A12   1
A14   3
```

Comment: Is this pandas or not?

Comment: Where do those numbers come from? What's the rule?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Windows Azure, or machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr=dataframe['old_col'].unique()
dataframe['new_col']=dataframe['old_col'].apply(lambda x: arr.index(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict

```
counts = {}
for s in strings:
    assigned_number = counts.get( s, len(counts) + 1 )
    counts[s] = assigned_number
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP would like to enumerate each possible string value, and not count them

Comment: Yeah, was too quick to the gun. I think my updated answer is better. Although, I'm assigning dict values multiple times

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OP wants to subtract the first number from the second and get the result. You can do it like this:

```
my_test = ['A12', 'A13', 'A13', 'A12', 'A14']

def numberMyData(data):
    try:
        nums = re.match('\w(\d)(\d)', data).groups()
        nums = nums[1] - nums[0]
        return (data, nums)
    except:
        return (data, 0)

my_new_data = list(map(numberMyData, my_test))
```

Then you have a list, looking like this:

```
[('A12', 1), ('A13', 2), ('A13', 2), ('A12', 1), ('A14', 3)]
```

If you want to print it in the format from your question, you can use something like this:

```
for data in my_new_data:
    print('   '.join([data[0], str(data[1])]))
```

Which joins the data with 3 spaces. The output looks like this:

```
A12   1
A13   2
A13   2
A12   1
A14   3
```

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that your data frame is 'df' and the field is titled 'Code'.
You can convert it into numeric values :

```
def convert_to_num(code):
    if code == 'A12':
        return 1
    elif code == 'A13':
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

df['New_Code'] = df['Code'].apply(convert_to_num)
```